# Ruby: Alias a method belonging to other class or module

Tags: ruby

While solving a coding challenge, I came across this instruction:

> If you need to debug, use `STDERR.puts`

So I thought of just aliasing `STDERR.puts` to something like `sp`:

```
>> alias :sp STDERR.method(:puts)

SyntaxError: (irb):96: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting end-of-input
alias :sp STDERR.method(:puts)
                 ^
```

As `alias` is a ruby keyword, it won't allow me to do that. Is there a way to alias a method belonging to another class/module?

---

<sub>I know I could wrap it into a local method (as I did). My intent here is to further understand the possibilities in ruby and the way `alias` work.</sub>

Comment: You can either define your own method or use the [Forwardable](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) module and let it create the method for you. In any case, `alias` and `alias_method` are only able to create real method alias for methods on the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I found, thanks to [Holger Just](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421705/holger-just), is to use [Forwardable](https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/forwardable):

```
require 'forwardable'
self.extend Forwardable
singleton_class.def_delegator "STDERR", "puts", "sp"

>> sp "a" "string"
astring
```

Although it is quite verbose and I'm not sure it would be better than just wrapping `STDERR.puts` into a new method.